# Travis-ci and Symfony3

Tags: mysql, symfony, travis-ci

Hi trying to set up travis with my symfony project

```
language: php
php:
    - '5.6'
    - '7.0'

services:
    - mysql

before_install:
    - php /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6/bin/composer self-update

before_script:
    - composer install
    - php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
    - php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --env=test
    - php bin/console hautelook_alice:doctrine:fixtures:load -n --env=test

script:
    - phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist --coverage-text
```

but I have this error in my build:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>   An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   php_network_getaddre     sses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known

Did I miss something? And do I really need to declare the mysql service?

Comment: Can you share a build log?

Comment: @joepd https://travis-ci.org/KevinRaimbaud/MelodyProject/builds/153910557

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have configured the database to live on a r[emote host by the name of `mysql`](https://github.com/KevinRaimbaud/MelodyProject/blob/dd27263a980835b361a98b4c9ac1dde804fe5dfb/app/config/parameters.yml.dist#L5). Please change it to `localhost` and see if it goes.

You will probably want to change the password for the `root` database user as well. Have a look at [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MySQL) for the initial values.

Comment: Ok so I have set up a `parameters_test.yml.dist` with localhost. But the composer install does not create the `parameters_test.yml`. How can I set up that? https://travis-ci.org/KevinRaimbaud/MelodyProject/builds/154082560

Comment: you just run cp parameters_test.yml.dist parameters_test.yml after composer install..although I prefer to name it parameters.yml.travis :)